An item with the same key has already been added in npoi
using var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
IWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);

When I execute the second sentence, the following error occurs：

When I open the workbook and do nothing and click save, an error occurs when I execute the above code. When I deleted all the blank lines below, it returned to normal.
